# Problem with getting params from paramMap

Tags: angular, typescript

So people i trying to catch a ID on the URL with paramMap but it always returns null anyone can figure the problem?
Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SenatorsService } from '../senators.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-senator-expenses',
  templateUrl: './senator-expenses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./senator-expenses.component.css']
})
export class SenatorExpensesComponent implements OnInit {
  senator: Senator[] = []
  id: number;
  constructor(private SenatorsService: SenatorsService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private a: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      this.id = parseInt(paramMap.get('id'));
      console.log(this.id)
    })
  }

}
```

Routing file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SenatorExpensesComponent } from './senator-expenses/senator-expenses.component';
import { SenatorsListComponent } from './senators-list/senators-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'senadores', component: SenatorsListComponent },
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'senadores', pathMatch : 'full'},
    {path: 'senadores/:id ', component: SenatorExpensesComponent} //This is the route i tryng to get the id
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

component.html

```
<p>
    <mat-toolbar>
        <span>Senators list</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
</p>


<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let senator of senators">
        <a matLine [routerLink]="['/senadores', senator.id]">{{senator.nomeSenador}}</a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

I try to use too "this.id = this.route.params" but dont work.

Comment: How are you navigating from SenatorsListComponent to SenatorExpensesComponent ? Can you please add the code where you are doing the route part >

Comment: I put on the code.

Comment: Can you please use a different route for the details page. For example - {path: 'senadores-detail/:id ', component: SenatorExpensesComponent}. And do the same change everywhere .... I don't think anything is wrong with code.

Comment: Tryed but returns the same

Comment: Can  you create a basic stackblitz replicating your issue ?

Comment: Can you re-verify whether each senator object has the property `id` by console.log(senators) in component ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for losing or time guys, actually the problem is in the line:

```
{path: 'senadores/:id ', component: SenatorExpensesComponent}
```

As you see have a space between id and the quotes, this is the problem i was searching for `this.id = parseInt(paramMap.get('id'));` instead of `this.id = parseInt(paramMap.get('id '));` But thanks anyway who tryed to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Actually the parseInt dont make much difference instead of return "null" return "NaN" but i try your code and returns null.